# Visual Studio extension to generate python docstrings

Tags: python, visual-studio, documentation

In visual studio, do you know an extension which can help to generate python docstrings using sphinx format?

I found this [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring) but it's only for visual source code.